# solana-test-validator "Illegal instruction" mac M1

Tags: error, build-bpf, m1

When I run `solana-test-validator` I get

```
Job 1, 'solana-test-validator' terminated by signal SIGILL (Illegal instruction)
```

**Configuration:**

- Mac m1 12.1
- cargo 1.62.1 (a748cf5a3 2022-06-08)
- rustup 1.25.1 (bb60b1e89 2022-07-12)
- solana-cli 1.10.32 (src:9cdd84bb; feat:1871643445)

Comment: curious, does this still happen?

Comment: Yeah, I have the latest updates.

Comment: What version of `solana-test-validator --version`. Im also on m1, dont remember having any issues with this

Comment: same as solana-cli 
`solana-test-validator 1.10.32 (src:9cdd84bb; feat:1871643445)`

Comment: Do you have rosetta installed (not sure if this is required, just comparing differences)

Comment: Do you mean rosetta enabled? if so I have my terminal with the option `Open Using Rosetta`

Comment: Interesting, you can try the old, delete and reinstall ;p

Comment: did you do `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license` to install rosetta 2 ? I think I don't have it installed lol

Comment: I did, I was prompted to whilst setting up my mac with my other -- tools

Comment: you don't need rosetta anymore, there are native mac arm64 binary releases now.  update the question with the output of `which solana`, `file $(which solana)` and `sysctl -n sysctl.proc_translated`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @trent.sol you don't need rosetta anymore, just use the native mac arm64 binary releases now.

To make it easier for others, install the releases from [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases).

you can follow the below steps:

```
wget https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/download/v1.11.6/solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2

tar jxf solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2

cd solana-release

echo 'export PATH=$HOME/solana-release/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```