# Issues with installing solana on m1 mac book (macOS Monterey v12.6)

Tags: rust, solana-test-validator, installation, m1, rustc

Followed guide https://dev.to/0xmuse/install-solana-on-m1-macs-without-rosetta-10m5 to install solana as I was reading about issues installing with rosetta. But after running `./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .` I get the error

error: failed to compile `spl-token-cli v2.0.17`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/qg/_nb652mx6lz1pb3kjhdqcksh0000gn/T/cargo-installLjxXCI`

Caused by:
package `time v0.3.14` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.59.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.57.0

I double checked to make sure my rustc version is `rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Same system here, I followed the answer in this question

[solana-test-validator "Illegal instruction" mac M1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/solana-test-validator-illegal-instruction-mac-m1)

and got binary from latest releases directly

```
wget https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/download/v1.14.3/solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2

tar jxf solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2

cd solana-release

export PATH=$HOME/solana-release/bin:$PATH
```